# Setting up Websolr with Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, websolr

I'm trying to add WebSolr support to my django powered app on Heroku.  They have detailed instructions for an implementation using Ruby:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr

But I can't figure out how to tie it up to Haystack.  Has any one done this?

Thanks.

Edit:

I was able to implement by modifying my `settings.py` file as:

```
HAYSTACK_URL      = os.environ.get('WEBSOLR_URL', '')
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': HAYSTACK_URL,

    },
}
```

Then running:

```
heroku run myproject/manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml
```

And uploading the contents of `schema.xml` to the advanced tab of the websolr interface.  And once I ran

```
heroku run myproject/manage.py rebuild_index
```

the index was built.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question/comments. Anything we might add to the official docs to help clarify this? Email us at info@onemorecloud.com.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the [Heroku Websolr Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr#haystack_for_django) to include a section on Django, based on your question. Thanks for that. For suggestions on our docs, drop a comment on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2333627).